# Angular and Ionic button click goes through data individually

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm trying to learn this and I can't figure out how to grab data from an array and index through it only showing the current value on screen. Where on the screen there's nothing to start. And when button is clicked it runs the runit() function and then you see 1, (click again) 2, etc.

```js
export class HomePage {
  public multipleOptions: Array < {
    option: any
  } > ;
  public currentValue: any;
  public currentOption: any;


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.multipleOptions = [{
        option: '1'
      },
      {
        option: '2'
      },
      {
        option: '3'
      },
      {
        option: '4'
      },
      {
        option: '5'
      }
    ]
  }

  runit() {
    let currentValue = this.multipleOptions;
    console.log(currentValue);
    this.currentOption = currentValue;
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<h2>{{currentOption}}</h2>
<button ion-button large (click)='runit()'>Start</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export class HomePage {
  public multipleOptions: Array < {
    option: any
  } > ;
  public currentValue: any;
  public arrayIndex: any; 

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.multipleOptions = [{
        option: '1'
      },
      {
        option: '2'
      },
      {
        option: '3'
      },
      {
        option: '4'
      },
      {
        option: '5'
      }
    ]
  }

  runit() {
    if(this.arrayIndex==null)
        this.arrayIndex = 0;
    else
        this.arrayIndex++;

    if(this.arrayIndex>=this.multipleOptions.length)
       this.arrayIndex = 0; //this is just to restart if you don't want this just block the increment

    this.currentValue = this.multipleOptions[this.arrayIndex].option;
  }

}
```

Html:

```
<h2>{{currentValue}}</h2>
<button ion-button large (click)='runit()'>Start</button>
```

Comment: It worked with some minor adjustment! Thank you so much! arrayIndex needed to be defined so i just did "public arrayIndex: any;" and the last line of the function (that starts with let currentValue = ...) I changed to "this.currentValue = this.multipleOptions[this.arrayIndex].option;" In the HTML the h2 is "<h2>{{currentValue}}</h2>" The reason I had to switch it was because the {{currentValue.option}} was throwing an error so I declared it in the definition of currentValue instead. You saved me so much time haha